# Refreshing Subclassed UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, subclassing, reloaddata

I've been at this one for a few days and can't get anything to work (there's some similar questions on SO but none have been quite right/done the trick).

So, I have a UITableView whose cells are subclassed (which are actually UITableViews with sublcassed UITableViewCells). Fundamentally, the table is similar to the one in this tutorial: www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1

When I select a cell, I want to change the styling (color specifically) of the subclassed cell to indicate it has been selected (likewise when unselected). I'm not sure how to reloadData for the subclassed cells... I can manipulate the singleton array where the info (indicating if the selected is selected or not) is found so that the cells adjust once the next click occurs.

Example for clarification (s=selected, u=unselected)

Say the table is currently like this

| U | S | S | U |

Now, I want to reset all the cells to unselected (so they should all appear as "U", so I reset the singleton'd array. Obviously the table still is the same. Now, say I select the final cell, this is what I get (which is correct):

| U | U | U | S |

The issue is I want it to be this once the array is reset but before the user selects another cell:

| U | U | U | U |

Sorry if this is unclear; I'll be around to elaborate on anything that may have caused confusion. Thanks SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055337/only-allow-one-checked-row-at-a-time-in-uitableview-preserving-animation/17056677#17056677). Basically, after you update the state of your array, you need to iterate over visible cells and reconfigure or reload them using one of the techniques described in the link.

Comment: thanks, marked as answer cause it got me in the right direction. it works on first run, but for some reason the subclassed cells return to their most recent state on the second (i'm logging the array and it's definitely reset)... any ideas?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand your scenario, so it would be helpful if you could post the relevant code. If I had to guess, I'd say you aren't configuring your cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and so rows that go off screen and back on are getting recycled cells that are in the wrong state.

Answer (score 0):

Use `selectedBackgroundView` property of `UITableViewCell` on `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
UIImageView *selBGView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourHighlightedImage.png"]];
 cell.selectedBackgroundView = selBGView;
```

Comment: I like where your head is at, but that won't help. The "state" is determined by my array, and while your proposal offers a different way to do *that* (I'll look into integrating that with the array as it might be cleaner ). Regardless, that *will not* work because cellForRowAtIndexPath isn't called in the subclassed implementation file ... If I could call cellForRowAtIndexPath (reloadData) from my normal class it'd work. For clarification, I want to set all the cells back to their original state when a non-tableview related method is called in the superclass.